# How to send customized Error response using express-jwt?

Tags: node.js, oauth, express-jwt

I want to know how to change the response of express-jwt when it is unauthorized, I tried with error handlers but its not working.

**This is my verification function**

```
const checkJwt = jwt({
secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
      cache: true,
      rateLimit: true,
      jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
      jwksUri: `https://dev-88888.com/.well-known/jwks.json`
  }),
 audience:'https://dev-******.com/api/v2/',
    issuer: `https://dev000000.com/`,
    algorithms: ['RS256']
  });
```

**This is what I am getting**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>UnauthorizedError: invalid token
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:102:22
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:75:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at verifyToken (/Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:100:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at fn (/Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/luisandrade/code/slothy_/back/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

**But What I want is**

```
{
    Error: 'Some Error message'
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from Documentation is that, you can pass a custom middle ware using `express` for error handling

```
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
     if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
     res.status(401).send('invalid token...');
     }
    })
```

[Documentation Reference](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#error-handling)